# Transform tool not working in all axis

Tags: transforms

I was working on a project for one of my CAD classes and everything was going fine. However, I am now having a problem that I can't transform (grab, extrude, translate) any of my points along the y-axis, but I can still move them along the x and z axis. This problem only seems to be occurring in this one project, so I know it has nothing to do with system preferences

Before Translate:
[image: Before Translate]

After Translate:[image: After Translate]

Edit: It seems that the frame of the car seems to be the only one having the problem, while the hood intake (which is it's own separate mesh) transforms fine in the y-axis

Comment: need more info :/

Comment: We cant really tell with so little info. Check the object scale or post some more additional data we can analize, like a screenshot, or possibly a link to your blend file